# Are there any significant differences (performance or otherwise) between using text-align versus flexbox's align-items to align text?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm aware of the differences between the two. I'm concerned with what is best practice and if there are any performance or a11y implications with using one or the other. Example usages of the these would be:

```
text-align: left;
```

or

```
align-items: flex-start;
```

In this hypothetical scenario, I'm just working with text positioning.

Comment: I would say both are completely different and the comparaison doesn't apply

Answer (score 0):

If your container is `flex-direction: row;` adding `align-items: flex-start;` will move the text to the top of the container as `align-items` defines how flex-items are aligned on the cross axis. You would probably want to use `justify-content: flex-start;` in this scenario as that would align the text to the left, or start of the container. If you're like me and tend to put a `text-align:center` on the `<body>` it can be nice to use `justify-content: flex-start` (and `align-items:center` usually) as flexbox is just an awesome, powerful tool that you can use with limited code and you don't have to manually add a `text-align` property to every piece of code you want to be aligned differently than center.